# Criteria Api: Use another parameter in multiselect, if the first one is null

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have a POJO class person which has two field. Lets assume only one of them holds a value and the other one is **always null**

```
public class Person {
     private String music;
     private String sports;
     ...
}
```

I want to fill either the one or the other into a List of DTOs via Criteria Api.
Here is a snippet of my (incomplete) Dao Code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PersonDTO> query = cb.createQuery(PersonDTO.class);
Root<Person> root= query.from(Person.class);

Path<String> musicPath = root.get(Person_.music);
Path<String> sportsPath= root.get(Person_.sports);

query.multiselect(/** TODO */);

List<PersonDTO> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Is there a way to use either *music* oder *sports* for the multiselect, depending on which of them is NOT null for the current record.
Or do i have to define a subquery to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `COALESCE` expression (see Ch. "Query Language", paragraph "Case Expressions" in the specification).

> Create an expression that returns null if all its arguments evaluate to null, and the value of the first non-null argument otherwise.

The corresponding criteria API are the `CriteriaBuilder.coalesce()` set of methods. Selecting a single string is something as simple as:

```
query.select(cb.coalesce(musicPath, sportsPath));
```

If you want a `PersonDTO` of course, you will have to make use of the `CriteriaBuilder.construct()` method *and an appropriate constructor*:

```
query.select(cb.construct(PersonDTO.class, cb.coalesce(musicPath, sportsPath), ...));
```

Comment: thank you very much, coalesce did the trick!
the 'construct' method wasn't necessary, i simply did a: 
query.multiselect(cb.coalesce(musicPath, sportsPath), ...)